# Making 3D animation visible inside a transparent 3D-Polyline

Tags: anylogic, presentation

How can you avoid a 3D-object disappear when entering a transparent 3D object? The attached foto shows that a patient disappears when seen from a certain angle, the person 3D-object is not visible. I've tried toggling settings back and forth on patient_presentation in Main and the 3D-objects itself with no luck. Is there a way to force the object to be visible?

[image]

Comment: You can also see that there are inconsistencies. In the first picture, the virus-logo is cut in half. Is how can this be fixed? Also, when panning in the model, som shapes will flicker. I am afraid that this will leave bad impression onto my case organization.

Comment: Flickering can be removed by changing the z-height (so different layers are at least 1 pixel apart vertically). The rest might be a bug. Try without transparent 3D stuff

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the comment, Benjamin. Right before I gave up on this, I found that removing the "Illuminate the object" made the 3D object show in the transparent 3D polyline.

[image: Properties of the 3D object]

Comment: that's clearly a bug, or is it not?... report it just in case :)